# Jenkins Build Failure: Error code 1. and Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and Docker containers and I am trying to deploy a Docker in Docker image through jenkins. I keep running into this error and I am not sure how to fix it.

`The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --requirement requirements.txt --index-url <url/simple>' returned a non-zero code: 1`

It fails here:

```
Step 7/13 : RUN pip install  --requirement requirements.txt --extra-index-url <url/simple>
 ---> Running in ddd7783gh
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, url/simple
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x83dx73hhf>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/ansible/
```

My Dockerfile is setup as:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim git nodejs npm
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash docker
USER docker
WORKDIR /home/docker
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --requirement requirements.txt --extra-index-url url/simple
RUN npm set registry <url>
RUN npm install yo generator-epic-project
COPY --chown=docker ./mongotool.py .
COPY --chown=docker ./init_scripts .
RUN chmod u+x init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./init.sh"]
```

I have tried many permutations of the pip install line as I thought that was where the issue was coming from but now I am not sure.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Seems like a Network error -  ```Name or service not known -  /artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/ansible/```

Comment: @TelinovDmitri how would I go about solving this? Is this an issue within the dockerfile or somewhere else. Wherein lies this network issue?

Comment: I believe here ```--extra-index-url url/simple``` should be a valid url, it cannot resolve that ```url/simple```